No behavior available in Primefaces widget
I want to fill an Primefaces inputText field by Javascript and trigger then the change event. In my understanding of the documentation of the inputText widget the callBehavior function would be the right way.
So my field looks like this:
<p:inputText id="myInput" value="#{myBean.value}">
   <p:ajax event="change" update="@this" onstart="console.log('Change triggered')" />
</p:inputText>

My JS function looks like this
function myFun() {
   const theId = // Have to get the id dynamically
   const inputWdgt = PrimeFaces.getWidgetById(theId);
   inputWdgt.jq.val('My new value');
   inputWdgt.callBehavior('change');
}

But in result neither the log in the onstart is printed nor the update is executed.
In my further investigation I saw, that the cfg object in the browser doesn't contain any behaviors. Hence it is obvious, that the callBehavior has no effect (since the function relates to these).
So the question would be, why are there no behaviors defined for the widget?

What version of PrimeFaces? I think a behavior is only attached when you have listener="#{bean.onChange}" calling a server side bean?

I'm using PrimeFaces 12.0.0. I tried it with adding the listener attribute. The method is called when I manually type something in the field. But there is still no behavior in the cfg, hence still no callBehavior effect.

One additional note: When I'm calling inputWdgt.jq.change() in the JS function instead of the callBehavior everything works fine. But I would prefer the original PrimeFaces API.

Its a bug. Can't believe no one ever reported this.
Bug: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/12887
PR: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/12888
It will be fixed in PF 14.0.8+
